# Simple search in existing excel file

Tags: c#, .net

I have an excel file in which in A column i have the name of the stock,
and in E and F column i have the stock rate and daily change.

I need a function which receives a string (stock name), 
and and for that string finds the suitable rate and daily change(the values in columns E and F).

Any ideas on how to implement? 
I am not familiar with excel in c# and looking at tutorials i am still in the blank.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Long long time ago but anyway. I'm trying to do something similar and came across this recently:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4x1k99a(v=vs.80).aspx

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have the following data in Excel:

```
    A         B         C         D         E         F
1   Stock                                   Price     Change
2   MSFT                                    $123.45   +0.67
3   ATT                                     $456.00   -1.23
4   IBM                                     $789.00   +9.87
5   GOOG                                    $543.00   -6.54
6
7
8  Stock:     IBM
9  Price:     {F1}
10 Change:    {F2}
```

Use the following formula in place of {F1}: `=VLOOKUP(B8, $A$2:$F$5, 5)`.

Use the following formula in place of {F2}: `=VLOOKUP(B8, $A$2:$F$5, 6)`.

(Do not type *{F1}* and *{F2}* in Excel - type in the formulae above.)

Take a look at documentation for [VLOOKUP function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx?CTT=1).